# Anylogic: Installing older version

Tags: anylogic

Our company license does not support the latest version (8.7.9) of Anylogic. Is there a possibility to install an older version of Anylogic? In a similar question about this topic (two years ago)  the following link was provided: https://www.anylogic.com/files/anylogic-professional-8.3.3.exe

This Link doesn't work anymore, even if i change 8.3.3 to 8.7.6

I have written an email to the Anylogic-Support, however there are only a few people working until January 10, so it can take a long time to get a response. So I wanted to ask if any of you have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add .x86_64.exe to the end, like `https://www.anylogic.com/files/anylogic-professional-8.7.6.x86_64.exe`. This is of course for 64 bit computer.

Comment: It works, thank you!

Comment: Glad that my answer was useful.