# AnyLogic | Material Handling Library – Cannot edit properties of "Material Item Type" agent

Tags: anylogic, agent

Whenever I create a **"Material Item Type"**, as soon as I click in **"Dimensions and Movement"** within the agent properties, AL starts to spam me with the following error:

[AnyLogic Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Caep.jpg)

Tested in two computers, both running Windows 10 with Intel CPU+AMD GPU.

**Issue also happens:**

1. While trying to follow [AL own's tutorial "Lead Acid Battery Production (Material Handling)"](https://anylogic.help/tutorials/material-handling/1-electrode-batches.html)"
2. When opening the source file [(available here)](https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/5e82c4f8-f11d-4c56-9ad4-1074732d9177?mode=SETTINGS) of the demo model and trying to edit the properties of the already-existing agent.
3. If creating an entirely new model and just placing a "Material Item Type" in an empty main and trying to edit its dimensions.

AL Version: AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition 8.8.5
OS: Windows 10 with all the latest updates (both machines).

Cheers!

Comment: definitely a bug in 8.8.5

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Felipe! :)

I'll try this with AL 8.3.3 to see if it works.

Do you know of any specific previous version of AL PLE which has this functionality working?

Cheers, mate! :)

Comment: Same here, can also reproduce. Reach out to support@anylogic.com to let them know, feel free to mention that Felipe and myself can also reproduce it. Should have been working in 8.8.4, never heard this before

Comment: i was using this feature A LOT in 8.8.4 so you should use that version

Comment: Thanks Felipe and Benjamin :)

Sadly, I've been unable to download 8.8.4 (PLE), so I am stuck until AL support is able to provide me with a link to it...

In the meantime, AL support confirmed this is indeed a bug present in version 8.8.5, with the solution being using " setWidth(), setLength(), setHeight() or setDimensions() functions" as per https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/material-handling-library/item-dimensions.html#dimensions

Cheers! ;)

Comment: you can download older version... check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70570348/anylogic-installing-older-version